# batch start program from current path

Tags: windows, batch-file, path, cmd

I have a batch file which contains:

```
start "" javaw -jar %CD%\example.jar
```

If both example.jar and batch file are in the directory without spaces (f.e. ProgramFiles) everything works fine. if these files are in directory with space (f.e. Program files) it cannot access example.jar file. Javaw program writes following: Unable to access jarfile: pathToMyDir\Program

Also tried this

```
start "" javaw -jar %~p0\example.jar
```

but result is the same..

any ideas? How to force the system to identify spaces as a part of a dirname?

Comment: did your try adding " (quotes) like  so: "%~p0\example.jar"

Comment: It may be safer to include both `d` and `p` modifiers, i.e. to use `%~dp0` instead of just `%~p0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put quotes around the path.

```
start "" javaw -jar "%CD%\example.jar"
```

Also, you don't really need to specify the %CD% unless I am misreading. You could just say:

```
start "" javaw -jar example.jar
```